# How to use angular 1 directives in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to migrate my Angular 1 directive to Angular 2. This is  my simple Angular 1 directive

**extCheckbox.html**

```
           <input type=checkbox
            name ="{{checkboxName}}"
            id="{{checkboxId}}"
            data-ng-readonly="isReadonly"
             data-ng-checked="isChecked"/>
```

This is my directive **extCheckbox.js**

```
var app = angular.module('Demo');

app.directive('extCheckbox', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {

            label: '@',
            name: '@',
            id: '@',
            isDisabled: '=?',
            isReadonly: '=?',
            isChecked: '=?',
        },
        templateUrl: './extCheckbox.html',
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (attrs.isChecked === undefined) {
                scope.isChecked =true;
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

I Migrated this to Angular 2 as follows,

**extCheckbox.Component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {UpgradeAdapter} from '@angular/upgrade';
const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();

let ExtCheckbox = upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Component('ext-Checkbox');

@Component({
    selector: 'ext-mycheckbox',
    template: '<ext-checkbox></ext-checkbox>',
    directives: [ExtCheckbox]
})


export class checkboxComponent{

}
```

**app.components.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {checkboxComponent} from './extCheckbox.Component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>checkboxComponent</h1><ext-mycheckbox></ext-mycheckbox>',
  directives:[checkboxComponent]
 })

export class AppComponent { 

}
```

The selector **my-app** element has been given in my **index.html** but the checkbox is not rendered in my page.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be bootstrapping the app incorrectly. You have to run Angular 1 and Angular 2 libraries side-by-side in order to use Angular 1 directives in an Angular 2 app. Below is an example of how I have setup a real, working hybrid angular application:

main.js

```js
import 'ts-helpers';
import './rxjs-operators';
import { upgradeAdapter } from './upgrade-adapter';
import { AppFlockModule } from '../appflock.module';

import app from '../appflock';

// workaround for cyclical dependency problem when using ng1 components in ng2 modules
// https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11069
upgradeAdapter['ng2AppModule'] = AppFlockModule;

upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, [app]);
```

upgrade-adapter.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeAdapter } from '@angular/upgrade';
import { uiRouterNgUpgrade } from 'ui-router-ng1-to-ng2';

// workaround for cyclical dependency problem when using ng1 components in ng2 modules
// https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11069
@NgModule({})
class DummyModule {}

export const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter(DummyModule);

uiRouterNgUpgrade.setUpgradeAdapter(upgradeAdapter);
upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Provider('$stateParams');
```

AppFlockModule is the main Angular 2 module for my application.

So the upgradeAdapter needs to be a singleton which you import (like in my example)

Also, in your example you have a typo: it should be upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Component('extCheckbox'); instead of 'ext-Checkbox'